# Is it important to split the data in train-validation-test when using XGBRegressor?

Tags: regression, xgboost

Is it important to split in train-validation-test when using XGBRegressor in order to avoid the possible problems caused by overfitting?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't learn a model and then test it in the same data, it will all be biaised... You HAVE to split in train-validation-test (or do Cross-Validation or wathever you want) to apply ANY model...
This is one of the basis of Data Science and Machine Learning, so I'd suggest you to find tutorials to learn basis before starting.